# Symfony / Doctrine: Limit query based on association ID without loading association or joining it

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Let's say I have a many-to-one relationship involving a `Person` entity and a `Position` entity. The foreign key lives on the `Person` entity. I want to write a query that limits results to people of a specific position *without having to join the `Position` association to the query or loading the Position entity*.

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
  ->select('Person')
  ->from('AcmeBundle:Person', 'Person')
  ->where('Person.position_id = :position_id')
  ->setParameter('position_id', 1)
;
```

This doesn't work, because there is no `position_id` property on the `Person` entity. Instead, I'd have to first join the `Position` association and do this:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
  ->select('Person')
  ->from('AcmeBundle:Person', 'Person')
  ->join('Person.position', 'Position')
  ->where('Position.id = :position_id')
  ->setParameter('position_id', 1)
;
```

or this:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
  ->select('Person')
  ->from('AcmeBundle:Person', 'Person')
  ->where('Person.position = :position')
  ->setParameter('position', $loaded_position_object)
;
```

Is it possible to limit my query by ID of Position without (1) joining the Position association or (2) loading the full position object?

Comment: What's the name of your attribute in the Person entity for the position relation? Isn't "position"? Why are you making where('Person.position_id = :position_id') instead where('Person.position = :position_id') on the first select?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you could do that. The name of the property is indeed `position` in this example, so I assumed I HAD to use a full `Position` object in Doctrine. I thought I tried that, but I guess not. If you post that as an answer I can accept.

Comment: It will not load the position object if you are not selecting it. You can utilize the lazy loading feature in the association mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead this

```php
...
->where('Person.position_id = :position_id')
...
```

you should do it like this

```php
...
->where('Person.position = :position_id')
...
```